# ns2 exponential distribution in packet size

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2, cc

I have some problem in ns2 about I want make my packetsize follow in exponential ditribution

to accomplish this , I use a Exponential Variable

Here is my code.

```
set exp [new Agent/Traffic/Exponential]
...
set rng [new RNG]
set rng seed 101
set size [new RandomVariable/Exponential]
$size set avg_ 123
$size use_rng $rng
$exp set packetSize_ [expr 1.0*[$size value]]
...
```

but when I saw the trave file, the packetsize is 416

```
- 0.659841 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 7 7
r 0.659874 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 7 7
+ 0.693121 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 8 8
- 0.693121 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 8 8
r 0.693154 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 8 8
+ 0.726401 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 9 9
- 0.726401 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 9 9
r 0.726434 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 9 9
+ 0.759681 0 1 exp 416 ------- 1 0.0 1.0 10 10
...
```

I'm confused about I think maybe the Exponetial Variables has a bug

so I add some code.

```
...
for {set j 0} {$j < 5} {incr j} {
puts [format "%-8.3f " [$size value]]
}
...
```

and the result is

```
238.606
102.588
12.960
71.759
41.372
```

so the variable is work

but not work in packetsize..

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

or can I modify the Exponential traffic generator (expoo.cc) to achieve this problem

by adding a Exponential Variables in expoo.cc ?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you're getting a value from the random generator only **once**, rather than for **each time** you send a packet.

Comment: So I had to modify the expoo.cc or the packet.h? 
If I add the ExponentialRandomVariable in expoo.cc ,
will it get a random value each time i send a packet??

Thanks alot!!